# FitNesse: Flow Mode using SetUp page to define enclosing table in .NET

Tags: .net, fitnesse

I'm working my way through the eBook [Test Driven .NET Development with FitNesse](http://fitnesse.s3.amazonaws.com/tdd_net_with_fitnesse.pdf) (PDF) and I've run into a problem creating a test page using flow mode with a DoFixture (Chapter 8 Coordinating fixtures).  Following through the tutorial in the chapter you create a test page using flow mode then refactor it to move the setup, including the first two tables, into a separate SetUp page (the refactoring starts on page 99 of the book).

I was able to create the initial flow mode test page successfully but I can't get the refactored version working, with the separate SetUp page.  I figure I'm missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Here is the contents of SettlementTests.SetUp:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {FitSharp\Runner.exe}
!path C:\...\Tristan.Test.dll

!|Tristan.Test.SettlementTest|

|Accounts before the draw|
|player|balance|
|Arthur|100|
|Ford|100|
|Trisha|100|
|Marvin|100|
```

And this is the SettlementTests.OneWinnerSixBallsFirstTry page:

```
|Tickets in the Draw|
|player|numbers|value|
|Ford|2,11,22,33,39,18|50|
|Arthur|1,5,4,7,9,20|50|
|Trisha|10,21,30,6,16,26|50|
|Marvin|12,13,14,15,16,17|50|

|Draw results are|1,5,4,20,9,7|

|Accounts after the Draw|
|Player|Balance?|
|Arthur|118|
|Ford|50|
|Trisha|50|
|Marvin|50|
```

For each table I'm getting the error message:

> Could not find fixture: Tristan.Test.SettlementTest.

(or whatever the fixture name specified in the table is)

I've created a parent SettlementTests suite page, and tried setting the SetUp page as both a Static page and as a Test page.  I get the same results in both cases.  The classpath is the same as the all-in-one page that works.

Is there something special I need to do to get flow mode working when I define the enclosing table in the SetUp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the !define and !path lines out of the SetUp page and onto the parent page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had a look at root and it's completely empty.

Comment: Move the !define and !path lines out of the SetUp page and onto the parent page.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, moving the `!define` and `!path` lines out of the SetUp page fixed the issue.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it.